# Get objects one by one in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-2.7, django-forms

I have filled 10 questions in one table of database. Whenever i print one question , all 10 questions are printed at one time.

But I want , one question to be printed then that question to be answered by the user, then the next question should appear.
so the next question should appear once the previous question is answered.

models.py

```
class Questions(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=500)

def __str__(self):
    return self.question
```

view.py

```
   def qpage(request):   
       questions = Questions.objects.all()
       return render(request, 'data/quit.html', {'questions': questions})
```

quit.html

```
      <form class="form"  method="post" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for q in questions %}

            <h3> {{ q.id }}.{{ q.question }}</h3>
            <input type ="text" name ="ans"  id = "q1a">

        {% endfor %}
        <button value ="Next">Next</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: Where do the answers go? Are they tied to a user? What you're trying to do is a bit more complex than what you've shown so far.

Comment: See https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html

Comment: Hello .  Let me explain you in detail.

Comment: Did you solve this?